# regular expression not working when check time in php

Tags: php, regex

below is my code for checking the variable is either time or not

```
function isTime($time) {

    if (preg_match("/^([1-2][0-3]|[01]?[1-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/", $time))
            {
        return true;
            echo "<script>alert('is a time');</script>";
            }
         else {
            echo "<script>alert('not a time');</script>";
           return false;
           }
         }
```

and this is expression fails when value like this `$time=00:08:33`, and working fine with time like `$time=01:08:33`, please modify this expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `[01]?[1-9]` pattern inside the first capturing group to `[01]?[0-9]`, so that it would also matches the number `00`. `[1-9]` Matches all the digits which falls within this range (*1 to 9*), and `[0-9]` matches all the digits from 0 to 9.

```
^([1-2][0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$
                   ^
                   |
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/5)

```
if (preg_match("/^([1-2][0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/", $time))
{
 ......
}
```